# Get the Count only values available in Specific list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have specific list of names (ABC, BCD, ......., JKL), Then separately I am maintain the another location with those list of name plus another separate words (Like - Off, ON, .... etc)

So I need count then no of name mention only in that specific list.

You can get my example in below G sheet, also Feel Free to contact me for any clarification.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bKA1KOs36ZDfR6VY18Md260MaFJWvO8uY3zto8jscOE/edit?usp=sharing

Indika[image: Sample]

Best regards

Indika

Comment: `=SUM(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2:O2,$A$2:$A$11,0))))` would get the number of matching values (not case sensitive). I'm unsure what you mean to do with `On` / `Off`

Comment: When I Looked it not working, If Possible Please try to apply formula for given Google sheet, Then you can understand it well

Comment: You tagged Excel formula. This works in Excel (which is not Google sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(XLOOKUP(D2:O11, A2:A, IFERROR(A2:A/0, 1),,,1), 
 LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(x))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Also Need your support to Get Monthly summary as well 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bKA1KOs36ZDfR6VY18Md260MaFJWvO8uY3zto8jscOE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @indikaprasanna https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNlLr.png

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution (I placed it in cell R2):

```
=ArrayFormula(BYROW(D2:O,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTBLANK(r)=COLUMNS(r),,
SUM(--REGEXMATCH(r,"\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b",1,A2:A11)&"\b"))))))
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks Lot, It working well, Let me to check with my actual Example and Then I will get back to you.
Best regard
Indika

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(IF(""=IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:O11, A2:A, 1, )), 0, 1), 
 LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(x))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Also Need your support to Get Monthly summary as well 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bKA1KOs36ZDfR6VY18Md260MaFJWvO8uY3zto8jscOE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365 you could use:
 `=BYROW(D2:O11,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(x,$A$2:$A$11,0))))))`
[image]

In older versions:
`=SUM(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2:O2,$A$2:$A$11,0))))`

[image]